# Complex regex to capture digits and words containing comma and spaces

Tags: java, regex, string

I have an input: `'BOOM', 'GRE,M', 'H SE', 1,2`

Now, I want to split the string on the conditions:

1. If it a word in the string is surrounded by a single quote, remove the single quote e.g `'BOOM'==> BOOM`, `'GRE,M' ==> GRE,M`, `'H SE'==> H SE` (the space should be kept). So, as the example shows, if the word has a space as in the "`'H SE'`" example, only the single quote should be removed and the space preserved.
2. if it is a word with no single quote, then do nothing e.g
    `1 ==>1` , `2==>2`

I have a regex `'(.*)'`, but this only takes care of words, within the single quotes. So, with the regex, I could easily get the following:
`BOOM`, `GRE,M`, `H SE` BUT NOT the `1`, and `2`. What regex will get all the values?

Comment: Why not split on `,` first and then remove the leading and trailing single quote?

Comment: are you trying to use replace them?

Comment: @SubOptimal there can be a `,` within quotes

Comment: Why you dont use  `string.replace("'","");` ?

Comment: @helpdesk Is `', '` a valid field value?

Comment: @MrT then 'GRE,M' will be splitted in 2 tokens, which is not the expected behaviour

Comment: @brso05 . It will split 'GRE, M' into "GRE", "M" which is not what I want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
\'(.+?)\'|([^\s,]+)
```

which means:

- `\'(.+?)\'` - any character (`.`) one or more times (`+?`) enclosed
  in single quote sings (`'`); `+?` is a [lazy quantifier](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-quantifiers.html#lazy), and it will match as few as possible characters to give a valid match,
- `|` - or, alternative
- `([^\s,]+)` - one or more of any characters, but not whitespace or commas, the `+` (I forgot about it in first version!) is quite important, without it it will match single characters

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/qH8vN6/3)

Example of extracting groups in Java:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        String example = "'BOOM', 'GRE,M', 'H SE', 1,2";
        Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("\'(.+?)\'|([^\\s,]+)");
        Matcher matcher = regex.matcher(example);
        while (matcher.find()) {
            if (matcher.group(1) != null){
                System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
            }else if(matcher.group(2)!=null){
                System.out.println(matcher.group(2));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what happens to an input with : "'1','2'"? Also, if I am to use the Matcher java regex class to get the words, there is no group to get in the statement? Any idea how one would use the Pattern and Matcher classes to get the words?

Comment: @helpdesk "'1','2'" are captured by `group(2)`, check my updated answer for example of extracting it

Comment: The backslash preceding the apostrophes in the regex is redundant.

Comment: @m.cekiera Thanks. Do you mind explaining the regex?

Comment: @helpdesk I updated answer, I hope I mede it clear, but ask if you have any doubts

Comment: @m.cekiera said : "..I forgot about it in first version!) is quite important, without it it will match single characters" So, which of the statements are correct: \'(.+?)\'|([^\s,]+)    OR    \'(.+?)\'|([^\s,])+ . Where should the + be in both regex statement?

Comment: @helpdesk sorry for that, I make a mistake after mistake. First one  \'(.+?)\'|([^\s,]+) is proper, as it capture multiple characters in a group, the second one \'(.+?)\'|([^\s,])+ will match same fragment, but will capture only first character in group(2). Sorry once again

Comment: @m.cekiera, how about a third condition that only selects words the way they are when not surrounded by single quotes? e.g "GRE,M, H SE" ==> GRE,M H SE.. Need to just use matcher.group(number) . . Could this third condition be added to the existing regex solution you gave?

Comment: @helpdesk if ther is always `, ` between words, you can use: `\'(.+?)\'|(?<=,\s|^)(.+?)(?=,\s|$)` [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/qH8vN6/4). In other case, it will be much harder, as `,` is treated as part of string and as delimeter

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/85209/discussion-between-helpdesk-and-m-cekiera).

Answer (score 2):

I write my comment in better understanding words :

If you use the replace-function of the string:

```
String ss = "'BOOM', 'GRE,M', 'H SE', 1,2";
System.out.println(ss.replace("'", ""));
```

you will get this output:

```
BOOM, GRE,M, H SE, 1,2
```

Or did i misunderstand the problem?

Comment: I need a regex. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your browser console

"'BOOM', 'GRE,M', 'H SE', 1,2".replace(/((?:')([^\']+)(?:')|([0-9]+))(?:, *)?/g, "$1 ==> $2$3, ")

You should get "'BOOM' ==> BOOM, 'GRE,M' ==> GRE,M, 'H SE' ==> H SE, 1 ==> 1, 2 ==> 2, "